# How to test same object instance in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, instance

Say I have the following objects in Javascript:

```
var a = { xxx: 33 };
var b = { xxx: 33 };
var c;

c = a;
```

What is the Javascript test that will tell me whether I am dealing with the same object instance? In other words, it should return false for a and b, b and c, but true for a and c.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You just need this

```
if(c == a) {
   // same instance
}
```

`a == b` and `b == c` will return `false`

Comment: And this, to me is actually a mistake in JS.  == is supposed to be value comparison, and === value + type comparison.  In my opinion, a == b should return true, a === b return false.  Instead, you have to use JSON operations to break it down into string values and perform the comparison of values.  The way it is now, there is no difference between == and === for object comparison.

Answer (score 15):

Just a standard equality test:

```
( a == c ) // true
( a == b ) // false
```

Comment: Why not triple equal?

Comment: @san.chez — It makes no difference when comparing objects.

Comment: @san.chez, it makes no difference _here_, but to switch off functionality I don’t want I would use triple equal here (and almost everywhere).

Answer (score 8):

I know the question is about checking if two objects are the same instance but this thread will not be complete without the following.

If you are after checking whether 2 objects are the same, a double equal `==` is enough. However, for value types (primitives), you may be in a for surprise. Check out the following:

```
var a = 1;  // Integer 1
var b = '1' // String '1'
if (a == b) console.log('Same.');
else console.log('Not same.');
```

Above will print `Same.`. To avoid that, use the triple equal `===` which means two things:

1. Are they the same value?
2. Are they the same type?

Or you can use `Object.is` method like `Object.is(a, b)`.

```
if (a === b) console.log('Same.');
else console.log('Not same.');
if (Object.is(a, b)) console.log('Same for Object.is.');
else console.log('Not same for Object.is.');
```

Above will print `Not same.` and `Not same for Object.is.`.

**Some More Info**

Below is some more information which has been copy/pasted from this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness):

> Which operation you choose depends on what sort of comparison you are looking to perform. Briefly:
>
> - double equals (==) will perform a type conversion when comparing two things, and will handle NaN, -0, and +0 specially to conform to IEEE 754 (so NaN != NaN, and -0 == +0);
> - triple equals (===) will do the same comparison as double equals (including the special handling for NaN, -0, and +0) but without type conversion; if the types differ, false is returned.
> - Object.is does no type conversion and no special handling for NaN, -0, and +0 (giving it the same behavior as === except on those special numeric values).
>
> Note that the distinction between these all have to do with their handling of primitives; none of them compares whether the parameters are conceptually similar in structure. For any non-primitive objects x and y which have the same structure but are distinct objects themselves, all of the above forms will evaluate to false.

---

**Conclusion**

My two cents on this would be to get into the habit of always using triple equals `===` because it *cannot hurt you* but double equals `==` can *indeed hurt you*. You may use double equals `==` when you just care about the value and the thing you are comparing are primitives; but even this is discouraged because it mostly means a flaw in design. Languages like TypeScript will even avoid that i.e. comparing a '1' to 1 without being explicit about it.

Comment: This should be the selected answer imo, as it also provides the complete background information.